Changing water level in an image dynamically based on slider value in MAUI
My sample project
I'm working on a MAUI (Microsoft .NET Multi-platform App UI) application where I have an image representing a glass of water. I want to dynamically change the water level in the glass based on the value of a slider control. Essentially, as the user moves the slider, the water level in the glass should adjust accordingly.
Here's what I have so far:
I have an image of a glass of water in SVG format.
I'm using SkiaSharp for rendering and manipulation of graphics.
I have a slider control that allows the user to select a value.
What's the best approach to achieve this dynamic water level adjustment based on the slider value in a MAUI application? Specifically, how can I programmatically update the water level in the SVG image when the slider value changes?
Any guidance, code examples, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

using Microsoft.Maui;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform;
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Android;
using SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg;
using System.IO;
using Android.Content;
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;

namespace MauiApp4
{
    public class GlassViewHandler : ViewHandler<GlassView, SKCanvasView>
    {

        public GlassViewHandler() : base(ViewHandler.ViewMapper)
        {
        }

        protected override void ConnectHandler(SKCanvasView nativeView)
        {
            base.ConnectHandler(nativeView);
            nativeView.PaintSurface += OnPaintSurface;
        }

        protected override void DisconnectHandler(SKCanvasView nativeView)
        {
            base.DisconnectHandler(nativeView);
            nativeView.PaintSurface -= OnPaintSurface;
        }

       

        private void OnPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
            var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;
            canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

            // Load SVG image of the glass
            var svgImage = LoadSvgImage("glass.svg");

            // Adjust fill level based on slider value
            //var fillHeight = VirtualView.FillLevel * e.Info.Height;
            //var fillRect = new SKRect(0, e.Info.Height - fillHeight, e.Info.Width, e.Info.Height);

            // Draw the glass with the adjusted fill level
            canvas.DrawPicture(svgImage, e.Info.Width, e.Info.Height);
        }

        private SKPicture LoadSvgImage(string filePath)
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                var svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
                svg.Load(stream);
                return svg.Picture;
            }
        }

        protected override SKCanvasView CreatePlatformView()
        {
            return new SKCanvasView(Context);
        }
    }
}




public class GlassView : SKCanvasView
{
    private float _fillLevel;

    public float FillLevel
    {
        get => _fillLevel;
        set
        {
            _fillLevel = value;
            InvalidateSurface();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaintSurface(e);

        var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;
        canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

        // Load SVG image of the glass
        var svgImage = LoadSvgImage("glass.svg");

        // Adjust fill level based on slider value
        var fillHeight = Height * FillLevel;
        //var fillRect = new SKRect(0, (float)(Height - fillHeight), (float)Width, (float)Height);

        // Draw the glass with the adjusted fill level
        canvas.DrawPicture(svgImage, (float)Width, (float)Height);
    }

    private SKPicture LoadSvgImage(string filePath)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            var svg = new SKSvg();
            svg.Load(stream);
            return svg.Picture;
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp4"

             x:Class="MauiApp4.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <local:GlassView x:Name="glassView" />

            <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="0.5" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>

Update
I am able to achieve what i am expecting but when i am reducing the height of rectangle or frame it is getting changed from bottom to top can anyone help in this

Could you please post more code snippets(e.g. xaml and mvvm) here so that we can help you better?

will share I tried with small POC as not able to get any concrete solution

Please provide the code that you already have and explain which part you're struggling with.

Updated the question with code

I tested the demo you shared, but it crashed on my side.

See other StakcOverflow answers
(easy) For (approx) filling a ceringe see this one usign pathLength

(not easy) For an exact percentage fill (by shape) see one calculating every with "pixels" using a native Web Component
50%, 20% or 80% filled:


I am facing this issue in MAUI .net.

The concept is the same; position an area FILL under a shape. Learning how to do it in native SVG should get your juices starting.
